# Galois finite extension

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K/ \mathbb{Q}$ be a finite Galois extension, $K \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R} \simeq \mathbb{R}^s \oplus \mathbb{C}^t$. 
Prove that either $s=0$ or $t=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The automorphisms of $K/\Bbb Q$ are continuous, so they extend to a completion. If we denote an infinite place by $\mathfrak{p}$, we know one completion is $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$. As all other completions are given by $\sigma(K)_{\sigma(\mathfrak{p})}$ and $\sigma(K)=K$ (since we are dealing with a Galois extension) we use the fact that $\text{Gal}\left(K/\Bbb Q\right)$ permutes the places transitively to conclude all completions are isomorphic as $\Bbb R$ vector spaces, in particular they have the same dimension.

Now as

$$K\otimes_{\Bbb R}\Bbb R \cong\prod_{\mathfrak{p}\text{ real}}K_{\mathfrak{p}}\times\prod_{\mathfrak{p}\text{ complex}}K_{\mathfrak{p}}$$

we conclude the result.

Answer (score 1):

[Addendum] It is known that here $s$ is the number of distinct real embeddings of $K$, and $d$ is the number of pairs of complex conjugate pairs of embeddings of $K$. I set out to prove this form of the claim. IOW I seek to prove that either all the embeddings of $K$ are real or none is. [/Addendum]

As $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed we can assume that $K$ is a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$. Let $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=n$. It is known that there are exactly $n$ embeddings $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n$ from $K$ to $\Bbb{C}$. But we also know that $K$, being Galois, has $n$ distinct automorphisms. It follows that the above embeddings are exactly the automorphisms of $K$, and thus have the property $\sigma_i(K)=K$. As $K$ either is or is not a subset of the reals the claim follows from this.

Comment: This oughta be a dup. Looking...

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/33988/11619)

Comment: I think slightly more needs to be said here:  I think you mean to say $\sigma_i\circ\sigma_j^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $K$ since the embeddings are maps into $\Bbb C$. And after identifying $K\subseteq\Bbb C$ via say $\sigma_1$, how does $\sigma_j$ act on $\Bbb C$ off of $K$ for $j>1$? You should need to apply to continuity/completions somewhere.

Comment: @Adam. Agree with your first point in that I tacitly picked one embedding to turn $K$ into a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$. But why would I need the automorphisms of $K$ to act on all of $\Bbb{C}$? They never need to be defined outside $K$, or if you prefer $\sigma_1(K)$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's hard to put into words the exact nature of the second objection because you're materially right. I mean that it's perhaps a bit strange for the student to go between embeddings and automorphisms, when the Galois condition is usually stated for automorphisms, and the question asks about not just $K$ but the completion (that was why I referenced continuity/completions). The phrasing also makes it more mysterious why normality should imply the (completely true) automorphism condition since it's a transition between definitions of "Galois" that is unexplained and non-trivial.

Comment: If you don't want to assume that $K$ is a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$ in the beginning, then a more accurate argument would be that we pick an embedding $f:K\to\Bbb{C}$, and then we get $n$ different, i.e. all, embeddings with the recipe $f\circ\sigma$ with $\sigma$ ranging over the group of automorphisms of $K$. Then all these embeddings share the image with $f$.

Comment: Re your second to last comment:  Right, that was what I was advocating for, my objection was pedagogical rather than mathematical, sorry if that was unclear. It might be that the student has not seen the connection between the two definitions of Galois that you (separately) use, namely normality, $\sigma(K)=K$, and having exactly $n$ automorphisms. I think what you've added, though small in character count is a great clarification. I would still personally say some words about density out of keeping it narrowly in-line with the question, but it's simple enough I like this form a lot! :-)

Comment: No problem, @Adam. I had skipped over a part, which I assumed to be common knowledge, but which in a way is at the heart of the question.